# Displaying information about a ticket purchase

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, active-record

My code works perfectly, however, I know my approach isn't best practice practice. I would appreciate the effort of anyone who tries to explain in details on how I could refactor this code using either(presenters, decorators or poros) - I have no deep understanding of either yet. 
Here is the code below:

In my events controller, I have a method called `tickets_report` defined as such

```
def tickets_report 
  @all_bookings = @event.bookings
  @ticket_types = @event.ticket_types
  @attendees = @event.attendees 
end
```

then, I use the `@ticket_types` instance variable in my views to plot a table as follows:

```
<tbody>

<% grand_quantity = ticket_left = quantity_sold = total_price = total_amount = 0 %>
<% @tickets.each_with_index do |ticket, index| %> 
    <% remains = ticket.quantity.to_i - ticket.user_tickets.count.to_i 
       amount = ticket.price.to_f * ticket.user_tickets.count.to_i
       grand_quantity += ticket.quantity 
       ticket_left += remains 
       quantity_sold += ticket.user_tickets.count 
       total_price += ticket.price.to_f 
       total_amount += amount 
    %>
    <tr>
            <td><%= index + 1%></td>
            <td><%= ticket.name %></td>
            <td><%= ticket.quantity %></td>
            <td><%= remains %></td>
            <td><%= ticket.user_tickets.count %></td>
            <td><%= number_to_currency(ticket.price)%></td>
            <td><%= number_to_currency(amount)%></td>
          </tr>

<% end %> 
 <tr class="gtotal">  
    <td colspan="2">Grand Total</td>
    <td><%= grand_quantity %></td>
    <td><%= ticket_left %></td>
    <td><%= quantity_sold %></td>
    <td><%= number_to_currency(total_price)%></td>
    <td><%= number_to_currency(total_amount)%></td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
```

My problem is this calculations done in the view is really not a good thing, and this is how far I have gone trying to fix this myself

```
module Events
  class Ticket
    def initialize(ticket)
      @ticket = ticket
    end 

    def name 
      @ticket.name 
    end 

    def quantity 
      @ticket.quantity 
    end 

    def price 
      @ticket.price.to_f 
    end 

    def user_count 
      @ticket.user_tickets.count.to_i 
    end 

    def remains 
      @ticket.quantity.to_i - user_count 
    end 

    def amount 
      price  * user_count 
    end 
  end 

  class TicketReportPresenter < Ticket 
    @@grand_quantity = @@ticket_left = @@quantity_sold = 0 
    @@total_price = @@total_amount = 0 

    def initialize(ticket)
      @ticket = Ticket.new(ticket)
      @@grand_quantity += @ticket.quantity.to_i  
      @@ticket_left += @ticket.remains 
      @@quantity_sold += @ticket.user_count 
      @@total_price += @ticket.price 
      @@total_amount ++ @ticket.amount 
    end 

    class << self 

      def grand_quantity 
        @@grand_quantity
      end 

      def ticket_left 
        @@ticket_left 
      end 

      def quantity_sold 
        @@quantity_sold
      end 

      def total_price 
        @@total_price
      end 

      def total_amount 
        @@total_amount 
      end 
    end    
  end
end
```

The new `tickets_report` method in my controller

```
def tickets_report 
  @all_bookings = @event.bookings
  @ticket_types = Events::TicketReportPresenter.new(@event.ticket_types.first)
  @attendees = @event.attendees 
end
```

However, things don't seem to be going right at this point. For instance I cannot call ActiveRecord relationships on the tickets object I defined. What is the best approach to refactor the logic present in the view, a detailed description and source code will suffice plus links to other resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out a better approach to avoid those complex logic in my view by using a presenter pattern. I create a presenter directory in my app folder and subfolder for the event controller and a `tickets_report_presenter.rb` file with the following code

```
module Events
  class TicketsReportPresenter
    attr_reader :event 

    def initialize(event)
      @event = event
    end

    def all_bookings 
      event.bookings.paginate(page: 1, per_page: 20)
    end 

    def attendees 
      event.attendees.paginate(page: 1, per_page: 20)
    end 

    def ticket_types 
      event.ticket_types.map do |ticket| 
         Report::Ticket.new(ticket) 
      end
    end 

    def grand_quantity 
      ticket_types.map(&:quantity).inject(0, &:+)
    end

    def ticket_left 
      ticket_types.map(&:remains).inject(0, &:+)
    end

    def quantity_sold 
      ticket_types.map(&:tickets_sold).inject(0, &:+)
    end 

    def total_price 
      ticket_types.map(&:price).inject(0, &:+)
    end

    def total_amount 
      ticket_types.map(&:amount).inject(0, &:+)
    end   

  end

  module Report 
    class Ticket
      attr_reader :ticket

      def initialize(ticket)
        @ticket = ticket
      end  

      def name
        ticket.name  
      end 

      def quantity 
        ticket.quantity.to_i 
      end 

      def tickets_sold
        ticket.user_tickets.count.to_i 
      end 

      def price 
        ticket.price.to_i 
      end

      def remains 
        quantity - tickets_sold 
      end 

      def amount 
        price * tickets_sold 
      end 
    end 
  end  
end
```

Then in my `tickets_report` action, I did this

```
def tickets_report 
    @presenter = Events::TicketsReportPresenter.new(@event)
end
```

This allows be to call the following methods in my view:

```
@presenter.all_bookings 
@presenter.attendees 
@presenter.ticket_types
@presenter.grand_quantity 
@presenter.ticket_left
```

Thanks to anyone who viewed this.